# How can I sort my items by both price and name?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I have a question on what to do next. I am working on this program and the requirements are.

#### Wings Coffee Shop

A local coffee shop sells a variety of different items shown below to their customers.   You are asked to write a Java application that can be used to keep track of these items.   Additionally, this program provides a way to print out a listing of the items.

```
Item Name            Price
Coffee               $1.00
Water                $2.00
Milk                 $1.50
Bagel                $1.25
Donut                $0.75
```

Your program will create a class, named Item.   This class has the following:

- A String instance variable to hold the item name
- A double instance variable to hold the price
- A constructor that takes a String and double to ini

Once you have this class created, you write a second class named CoffeeDriver.   This class has the following methods:

- sortName – this method sorts the array of items by item name and then displays the name and price of all items on the screen
- sortPrice – this method sorts the array of items by item price and then displays the name and price of all items on the screen
- main - It creates an array of Item objects using the data above to set each Item's information.
- A get and set method for each instance variable

This is all I have so far. I am having a hard time thinking how to sort an array. So if I sort 2 different arrays how do I keep them in proper order. Like for instance `coffee = $1` how do I sort it and keep those together.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoffeeDriver {

//main method
    public static void main (String[] args){
        String[] itemName = {"Coffee, Water, Milk, Donut, Bagel"};
        double[] itemPrice = {1.00, 2.00, 1.50, 0.75, 1.25};
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String decision;

        System.out.println ("Welcome to Wings Coffee Shop");
        System.out.println ("We have a great list of tasty items on our menu.");
        System.out.println ("Would you like to see these items sorted by");
        System.out.println ("name or by price? (n/p): ");
        decision = input.nextLine();
            if (decision == "n"){
                sortName(itemName);
                }
            else {
                sortPrice(itemPrice);
                }
    }

//method to sort by item name and display
    public static void sortName (String[] array){
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.println (array[i].toString());
            }
    }

//method to sort by item price and display
    public static void sortPrice (double[] array){
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.println (array[i]);
            }
    }
}


public class Item {
    private String name;
    private double price;

    Item(String itemName, double itemPrice){
        itemName = name;
        itemPrice= price;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String itemName){
        itemName = name;
    }

    public double getPrice(){
    return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double itemPrice){
        itemPrice = price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? People generally appreciate it if you tag homework questions so we can answer appropriately :)

Comment: By the way, +1 for saying what you've done so far and for saying exactly what you're having trouble with!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correction to the **Item** class definition.

You need to assign parameters to the fields (In OP you've assign field to parameter)

Use Comparator object parameter to implement sorting for individual field.

```
   List<Item> items=new ArrayList<Item>();
   items.add(new Item("A",1.2));
   items.add(new Item("Z",10.2));
   items.add(new Item("B",2.3));
   items.add(new Item("Y",5.4));
   items.add(new Item("B",1.3));


  java.util.Collections.sort(items,new Comparator<Item>()
   {
       public int compare(Item a,Item b)
        {
          if(a.getName().compareTo(b.getName())>0)
            return 1;
          else
          if(a.getName().compareTo(b.getName())<0)
            return -1;
          else
             return 0;            
        }
        public boolean equals(Object a)
         {
            return false;
         }
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you simply make the `compare` method return `a.getName().compareTo(b.getName())`? Also: a `Comparator` usually doesn't need an `equals()` implementation.

Comment: Agree! That's true but in this code I just want to add pattern of return value of compare method for comparing non-string data.

Answer (score 0):

"I am having a hard time thinking how to sort an array"

You could take a look at the 'java.util.Collections' class. It contains a bunch of useful methods, including tools for sorting lists. You'll need to read up on how to implement a 'Comparator' object, too.

EDIT: Also think carefully about exactly what you want to sort. There is a difference between sorting items by price and sorting the prices.

I've assumed this is homework so I won't give you the whole answer, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: For sorting arrays, `java.util.Arrays` should be used instead of `java.util.Collections`

Comment: @Costi: Good point. I tend to prefer Lists over arrays, but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at Arrays.sort that should facilitate what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You would not sort both arrays in parallel (which is possible, but not in the Java API, and thus had to be done by yourself), but create Item objects (in a array or collection) from the name and price information, and then sort this array/List (or use a sorted collection like TreeSet).

For this, you may want to look at `java.util.Comparator` and `java.util.Collections.sort` (or `java.util.Arrays.sort`).

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo Java code (Using an object representation for e.g. (Double) instead of double would be easier as we could make use of the existing compareTo method which is implemented at the object level.)

```
class Item {
 private final String name;
 private final Double cost;
 :
 : //Getters and setters
 :
};

public static void sortByName(List<Item> items) {
 Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<Item>() {
     public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return (Item)o1.getName().compareTo(o2);
     }

     public boolean equals(Object o1) {
           return ((Item)o1).getName().equals((Item)o2).getName()) )
     } 

 }); 

public static void sortByPrice(List<Item> items) {
 Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<Item>() {
     public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return (Item)o1.getCost().compareTo(o2.getCost());
     }

     public boolean equals(Object o1) {
           return ((Item)o1).getCost().equals((Item)o2).getCost()) )
     } 

 });
```

Answer (score -2):

```java
public void sortTShirt(List<TShirt> matchingTShirts, String outputPreference) {
        if (outputPreference.equals("Price")) {
            matchingTShirts.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(t -> Double.parseDouble(t.getPrice())));
        } else if (outputPreference.equals("Rating")) {
            matchingTShirts.sort(Comparator.comparing(TShirt::getRating).reversed());
        } else {
            matchingTShirts.sort(Comparator.comparing((TShirt b) -> Double.parseDouble(b.getPrice())).reversed()
                    .thenComparing((TShirt b) -> Double.parseDouble(b.getRating())).reversed());
        }
    }
```

Comment: please edit and format your code (min 4 leading spaces) - also add a bit of text to describe what the method is doing :)